# Mongoose isn't saving edited document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've recently started playing with Node.js and I've been trying to create a basic blog (using Express, MongoDB and Mongoose) where I can create, edit and delete posts. I've managed to get everything working except the edit. Here's an example of the routes to create a post so you can see my approach. I've written it using CoffeeScript. If this is a problem I can compile and edit the post.

```
# [get] new post
  app.get "/posts/new", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) ->
    res.render "posts/new",
      title: "New Post"
      user: req.user

# [post] new post
  app.post "/posts", (req, res) ->
    post = new Post(req.body.post)
    post.save (err) ->
      unless err
        res.redirect '/posts'
      else
        res.redirect '/posts/new'
```

The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to edit/save a post (document). I'm not seeing any errors yet the document in the database isn't updating. I'm using the PUT request as I read that it's converted by Express. My edit routes are as follows:

```
# [get] edit post
  app.get "/posts/:id/edit", (req, res) ->
    Post.findById req.params.id, (err, doc) ->
      res.render 'posts/edit',
        title: 'Edit Post View'
        post: doc

# [put] edit post
  app.put "/posts/:id", (req, res) ->
    Post.findById req.params.id, (err, doc) ->
      doc.post = req.body.post.content
      doc.save (err) ->
        unless err
          res.redirect '/posts'
          console.log 'edit success'
        else
          console.log 'edit failed'
```

Here is the form from the edit post template:

```
form(method='post', action='/posts/' + post.id)
    input(name='_method', value='PUT', type='hidden')
    fieldset
        legend Editing post
        div.clearfix
            label Post
            div.input
                input(name='post[content]', class='xlarge', value="#{post.content}")
        div.actions
            input(type='submit', value='Save', class='btn primary')
            button(type='reset', class='btn') Reset
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? I've followed a tutorial in a book and this is what's done yet it doesn't seem to be working for me. If I saw some errors it would be a start but as I'm extremely new to Node.js (and JavaScript, really) I don't know where to look now.

Thanks for your time, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Document.set](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set) method. It will mark your property as modified.

```
doc.set post:req.body.post.content
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain a little further as I'm new to this. From books/tutorials I've seen, I've just come across doc.save and doc.update when saving/updating something that's been edited. Do you know why the code I have isn't showing any errors yet not actually doing anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a value to a mixed/nested property, Mongoose doesn't know that it was modified; it can only watch properties that are typed. When you save, Mongoose is only updating the properties that it knows to have been modified.

To deal with this, Mongoose documents provide the `setModified` method to mark the altered property.

```
doc.post = req.body.post.content
doc.setModified 'post'
doc.save (err) -> ...
```

That's fine when you know exactly what property you're updating and there's just one, but `doc.set` is probably the better option in most cases. When you pass `doc.set` an object representing the changes you want to make, you can think of it as an update that operates on the *Mongoose document* -- as opposed to an actual update to the database.

The `doc.set` method will move through the update object and assign each property to the document, correctly marking them as modified. Then `save` will be successful.